# implement express controller class with typescript

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, routes

I'm doing an express app with typescript.
The router code is:

```
let user = new User();
router.get("/", user.test);
```

the user class is

```
export class User {
   test(req, res, next) {
      // this === undefined
   }
}
```

the problem is that the this object is undefined inside test method. Is there a better way to implement express routing?

Comment: you can try to use some library, like [routing-controllers](https://github.com/pleerock/routing-controllers)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to use the [bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to keep the scope of `this` when the method is invoked:

```
let user = new User();
router.get("/", user.test.bind(user));
```

Or you can do that in the `User` constructor:

```
export class User {
    constructor() {
        this.test = this.test.bind(this);
    }

    test(req, res, next) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Another option is to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
let user = new User();
router.get("/", (req, res, next) => user.test(req, res, next));
```

Comment: What about the memory will the class will be removed from the memory when the function ends...?

Comment: @usama I'm not sure what you mean. The class won't be removed, the instance might be, depending on if anyone has a reference to it. Which function are you referring to?

Comment: I am referring to the instance i want to use classes with express.js routes instead of the functions.

Comment: @usama You're asking if the instance will be deleted from memory after the request has been handled by the function (if you put it into the router)? If so, then the answer is no. You pass a reference to the method, which is bound to a specific instance, and so there's a reference for that instance, which will prevent the GC to clear it from memory.

Comment: yes you correct i am asking that.Thanks for explaining it what if i use Static Methods of the class for the router methods then what about the memory is this is good way of handling it ...?

Comment: @usama If you're using static methods then there's no need for an instance to begin with. But in that case you can just have exported module functions. But, why do you care so much about the memory consumed by a single instance? it shouldn't bother you.

Comment: The app is large and their will be around 30 classes so that is why i am bothered about memory instance.Yes i am doing with Module.Export with Static methods.
so with 30 classes with static methods it would be fine right...?Thanks Again

Comment: @usama You shouldn't worry about 30 instances, that's a micro optimization which sounds to me like a waste of time.

Comment: Nitzan what would you suggest here..? Basically i wanted to follow OOP based approach this is why i am asking this...

Comment: @usama I'm not a fan of classes who only have static methods, and in this case I don't see the reason for classes at all, unless the class is saving some sort of state between requests. What I'm doing is having a module per router which has the exported functions. But there are plenty of other ways of course.

Comment: Great Thanks for sharing your Approach.

Comment: I found another interesting answer that worked for me. I used `test = (req, res, next) => { ... }` instead of `test(req, res, next) { ... }`. I am curious to know why I shouldn't use this way of adding handlers?

Answer (score 18):

You can use `export default` and instantiate the controller so it can be used without instantiation in whichever file you've imported the controller.

**register.controller.ts**

```
import { Router, Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

class Register {

    constructor() {    
      this.register = this.register.bind(this);
    }

    register(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
      // ... removed for brevity
    }
}

export default new Register();
```

**server.ts or auth.routes.ts**

```
import registerCtrl from '../controllers/auth/register.controller.js';

// ... removed for brevity

router.post('/register', registerCtrl.register);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of TS, you can create a static method with or without an accessor modifier, and call that method in the router without instantiating a class:

```
export class UserController {
    // arrow function
    public static test: RequestHandler = async (req, res, next) => {
        // ...
    }

    // regular function
    public static async getAll(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and in the router use it as:

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { UserController } from '/controllers/UserController';

const router = Router();

...
router.get('/test', UserController.test);
....
```