# How to get the same datatype as of Post method of express in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I want to pass my request and response to controller but I don't get the correct data type.

I have my Router below

```js
import express from 'express'
import { ProjectController } from '../controllers/projectController';

const router = express.Router()
const projectController = new ProjectController()

router.post('/', function(request, response) {
    projectController.save(request, response)
})

export default router
```

The data of request above is `export interface Request extends http.IncomingMessage, Express.Request` and it take from `/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts`

The data of response above is `export interface Response extends http.ServerResponse, Express.Response` and it take from `/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts`

I have my Controller below

```js
export class ProjectController {
    public save(request: Request, response: Response) {
        response.status(200).send
    }
}
```

The datatype of request above is `interface Request extends core.Request { }` and it takes from `/node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts`
The datatype of response above is `interface Response extends Body`.

The problem is that when I pass request and response from post method to controller's save method, the datatype is different and it doesn't show status and send method.
So how do I declare a function with the same data type as of the post method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45763285/5744323).

*router.ts*

```js
import express from 'express'
import { ProjectController } from '../controllers/projectController';

const router = express.Router()
const projectController = new ProjectController()

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    projectController.save(req, res)
})

export default router
```

*controller.ts*

```js
import { Router, Request, Response } from 'express'

export class ProjectController {
    public save(req: Request, res: Response) {
        res.status(200).send({message: 'Reached here'})
    }
}
```